# Even after FIltering the Data from a Dataset, values still can be seen while plotting

Tags: pandas

I am stuck in this investment analysis spark fund code. I have filtered out by country code where my data is only having only 3 countries. However, when I run a boxplot against it, the entire country list is shown.

```
#Filtering the top 03 Countries where maximum Investments have taken place

master_venture_new = master_venture[ (master_venture.country_code =='USA') | (master_venture.country_code =='GBR' ) | (master_venture.country_code =='IND')]
master_venture_new.head(3)

sns.boxplot(x='country_code', y = 'raised_amount_usd', data = master_venture_new)
plt.show()
```

[Resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiPDr.png)

need help understanding how to go around this.

Answer (score 0):

To don't include the the levels that you filtered out, you have to convert the column to category after filtering the dataframe or you will need to drop the unused levels of your categorical features before plot the graph.

The code to do that is:

`master_venture_new.country_code.cat.remove_unused_categories(inplace=True)`